# error in using heatmap() as the plot input of ggsave()

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I want to save the output of stats::heatmap() in ggplot2::ggsave(), but the output is not a plot, and I receive an error. 
Here is the code:

```
data("iris")
col<- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))(20)

ggsave(filename = "heatmap.png", plot = heatmap(x = cor(iris[,-5])  , col = col, symm = TRUE),device = "png", dpi = 450)
```

Now while the code actually works and saves the `heatmap.png` in the R working directory, it also returns an error.

> Saving 3.74 x 8.49 in image 
>   Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") : 
>   no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "list"

I reckon it is because the output of `heatmap()` is not a plot and it is a list.

Since I am using the `ggsave()` as part of a **`downloadHandler()`** in Shiny, the error  interrupts the downloading/saving process.

I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 5):

The syntax of `ggsave()` is

```
ggsave(filename, plot = last_plot(), device = NULL, path = NULL,
  scale = 1, width = NA, height = NA, units = c("in", "cm", "mm"),
  dpi = 300, limitsize = TRUE, ...)
```

The plot to be stored must be passed as the second argument. In order to do that you must be able to assign your plot to a variable. This can be done with plots created by `ggplot()`:

```
p <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
class(p)
## [1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

This piece of code does not show any plot, but it has actually stored a plot in `p`. You can render it by just running `p` or `print(p)`.

Base plot functions are different. They directly create a plot as a side effect. So this code will show the plot, even though the output is assigned to a variable:

```
p2 <- heatmap(x = cor(iris[, -5]), col = col, symm = TRUE)
```

And `p2` is now a `list` and not a plot:

```
p2
## $rowInd
## [1] 2 1 3 4
## 
## $colInd
## [1] 2 1 3 4
##  
## $Rowv
## NULL
## 
## $Colv
## NULL
```

So, passing `p2` to `ggsave()` won't work because it does not actually contain the plot.

But it is still possible to store base plots in files by using graphics devices.

For example, you can create a `png`-file like this:

```
png(filename = "heatmap.png")
heatmap(x = cor(iris[, -5]), col = col, symm = TRUE)
dev.off()
```

And there are other devices that can be used similarly, e.g., `jpeg()`, `pdf()`, and `tiff()`.

You can use the device in `downloadHandler()` as follows:

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "heatmap.png",
    content = function(file) {
      png(filename = file)
      col <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))(20)
      heatmap(x = cor(iris[, -5]), col = col, symm = TRUE)
      dev.off()
    }
  )
```

Comment: I really appreciate your  explanatory and comprehensive response, but as I said I want to use it in a Shiny applet, with `downloadHandler()`. The `png()` does not work with it seemingly. The rest are totally true, and it definitely helps others who don't know `ggsave()` arguments and so.

Comment: I can use `png()` within a `downloadHandler()` without problems. What exactly is not working?

Comment: So I have to say that I cannot make it work with downloadHandler(). May you please provide me the working code of png() and downloadHandler() ?

Comment: Ok Now It works! I figured out that I was using the file argument of downloadHandler() in a wrong way for png(). Thanks Stibu!

Comment: I added the code as another answer, but if you edit your answer and append the downloadhandler() code to it, I would remove mine.

Comment: `lapply(1: length(hm_lst), function(i){
  ggsave(plot = hm_lst[[i]], 
         filename = paste(names(hm_lst)[i], ".pdf"), 
         width = 15)
})` It fails I see why it fails due to ggsave ..How do i save the same I want to save each plot into individual files

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the comprehensive answer of @Stibu, in order to make the png() work with Shiny::downloadHandler():

```
output$download_correlation <- downloadHandler(
             filename = "correlation_plot.png",
             content = function(file) {

                     #preparing the dataset from an external function
                     corr_data <- correlation_data() 


                     #colors of the heatmap
                     col<- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))(20)

                     png(file)
                     heatmap(x = cor(x =as.matrix(corr_data)) , col = col, symm = TRUE)
                     dev.off()                   
     )
```